# How to interleave multiple ActiveRecord association queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have five categories with about five posts each. E.g.

```
=> category_a.posts
=> #<Post id:01>, #<Post id:02>, #<Post id:03> etc

=> category_b.posts
=> #<Post id:10>, #<Post id:11>, #<Post id:12> etc

=> category_c.posts
=> #<Post id:20>, #<Post id:21>, #<Post id:22> etc
```

I'd like a collection of children where they are interleaved (as evenly as possible), i.e.

```
#<Post id:01>, #<Post id:10>, #<Post id:20>, #<Post id:02>, #<Post id:11> etc
```

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by Dave Schweisguth is ok and probably lets you know what you need to know to solve the problem. But, that solution does not let you choose the order the items get interleaved in. Here is a, hopefully, more general solution:

```
def full_zip(*args)
  max_len = args.map(&:length).max
  ([nil] * max_len).zip(*args).flatten.compact
end
```

and then this would be used like `full_zip(category_a.posts, category_b.posts, category_c.posts)` or `full_zip(*[cat_a, cat_z].map(&:posts))`. Use the categories in whatever order you want them in.

Edit: one problem with this one is if the original lists have nils in them you want to keep.

Comment: The next evolution of my solution would be to pad all of the arrays to a given length with `nil` and drop the sort to preserve order, but this is nicer. Small suggestions: `max_len` = `args.max_by &:length` and just use `Array[max_len]` instead of `[nil] * max_len`.

Comment: that `Array[max_len]` thing is probably more semantically correct, but I think its `Array.new(max_len)` or `Array.new(max_len, nil)`. The multiplication trick is nice because it is maybe a little more easy/general when making new arrays (from old ones, or with fancy shapes without having to use flatten).

Comment: the `max_by` trick is nice too, but it would have to be `foo.max_by(&:length).length` I think, because max by just returns the element.

Answer (score 1):

It's only five queries and around 15 models, so it would be fine to do it in memory:

```
 posts =
   [category_a, category_b, category_c, category_d, category_e].
   map(&:posts)
   sort_by(&:length)
 posts.first.zip(*posts[1..-1]).flatten.compact
```

Putting the longest array first prevents `zip` from dropping elements from the arrays in its arguments that are longer than the array it's called on. `compact` removes any `nil`s created by `zip` if the arrays in its arguments are longer than the array it's called on.

Comment: My understanding is that with this, zip will ignore items items in category b through e that have a higher index in their original arrays that are higher than the highest index in category a, if that makes sense. See here for details: http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip.

Comment: another thing, though I'm not sure, is that with this, posts of category_a will be interleaved with lists of posts. this can be illustrated with "[1,1,1].zip([[2,2,2], [3,3,3], [4,4,4]])" => [[1, [2, 2, 2]], [1, [3, 3, 3]], [1, [4, 4, 4]]]. I think a "*" symbol before the array you send to the zip function will destructure that array and solve this. Alternatively, I think you could flatten after you "map(&:posts)" (I do think you will also need that extra colon there).

Comment: Since the edits, my above two comments should no longer be problems. One thing to consider now though is that the user of the program cannot really control what order the posts get zipped in now, and that is only determined by whatever category has the most posts. It also suffers from the same problem as mine if you want to maintain nils. If that's important to anyone, please leave a comment and I can add that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I addressed them. Good point that this method gives up control of the ordering.